# how to give input file to read using textract inside flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, upload

I am trying to read contents of files like .txt,.docx,.pdf and so on with textract. when i use the below code, it throws error:

```
   @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload():
        request_file = request.files['file']
        text = textract.process(request_file.stream)
        return (text)
```

when i uploaded a docx file,

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 26, in exists
>   os.stat(path) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer,
>   instance found
>   10.0.2.2 -- [12/Apr/2018 09:04:58] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -

How can i send these files with different extension into textract with flask?

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem. We have to first upload the file on the server and then access it. It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I think Textract cannot process file stream

Try instead with exact file path and its extension like :

```
textdata=textract.process("C:\some_path_to_file",extension=".pdf")
```

It works and give it a try

Comment: this is inside flask. I want to upload from http request and process the file. So I dont want to mention the file path.